# Twitter and R ( Curl:curl_fetch_memory Error)

Tags: r, twitter

Here is my Code :

```
install.packages('twitteR',dependencies=T)
install.packages('httpRequest')
install.packages('purrr')
install.packages('httk')
install.packages('httpuv')
install.packages("base64enc") 

library(twitteR)
library(plyr)
library(purrr)
library(httk) 
library(httpuv) 

my_key<- "*****"
my_secret<- "*****"
my_access_token<-NULL
my_access_secret<-NULL
setup_twitter_oauth(my_key,my_secret,my_access_token,my_access_secret
                    )

tweets=searchTwitter('#abortion',n=1500)
length(tweets)
tweets.text=laply(tweets,function(t)t$getText())
pos=scan('positive-words.text',What='character',comment.char=';')
```

I am getting the following error : Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't connect to server.

Please provide me how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: Hey @addy, a couple of remarks: #1 Redact your credentials, #2 provide minimal examples (what are all the packages for?), #3 consider using [rtweet](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet) instead of `twitteR` as the latter one is deprecated, #4 then follow the [guide here](https://mkearney.github.io/rtweet/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a minimal working example. I believe you need to provide all four keys/secrets.

```
library(twitteR)
library(ROAuth)

api_key <- "***"
api_secret <- "***"
access_token <- "***"
access_token_secret <- "***"
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)

tweets <- searchTwitter('#abortion', n = 10)
df <- twListToDF(tweets)
```

Comment: I am getting a different error  :

Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'

Comment: That sounds like the keys/secrets you provide are not right. The code above works when I supply the actual information.